# Implicitly add users to a group in UNIX through membership of a second group

Tags: unix, users, groups

I have two groups on my machine, `groupa` and `groupb` - in `groupa` I have two users, `user1a` and `user2a`.

I would like to grant to members of `groupa` the privs to access `groupb` resources (run commands, view files etc). I think this probably involves using `visudo`, but I may be wrong.

What I would like to achieve is the equivalent of:

```
usermod -a -G groupb user1a
usermod -a -G groupb user2a
```

but to do it at the group level so that if in future `user3a` is added to `groupa`, the user also automatically has the privs for `groupb`.

As you may have guessed, Unix admin isn't my main area of operation !

How do I go about it?

Thanks in advance

Rich

Answer (score 3):

You can't do nested groups out of the box, like you could do in Active Directory.  A [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/13498/groups-and-permissions-nested-unix-groups) got an answer pointing to [Linux trustees](http://freshmeat.net/projects/linuxtrustees/).

Answer (score 2):

I think it can't be done, other than by defining your own wrapper for useradd and enforcing it's use or maybe by a cron script that periodically checks members of groupa and, if necessary adds them to groupb.

Answer (score 0):

Using sudo to achieve this requires that the user prefix all their commands with `sudo -g groupb`.  The user won't BE in the `groupb` group, the user will just have permission to switch to that group and run commands.  `visudo` is the command to edit the sudoers file that controls who is permitted to use sudo for what.

Doing this requires at least 1.7.0 and opens a [security exploit](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/alerts/runas_group.html) in versions up to 1.7.4p3

```
%groupa ALL = (:groupb) ALL
```

It is probably better to just manually add the user to both groups.  A PAM wizard might be able to automate that process, but it would only work for login shells or applications that use PAM for identifying the user rather than reading /etc/group and /etc/passwd directly